# Joining Tables and Concatenating Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using MS-SQL 2008r2, I have two tables, with multiple secondary ID's which I need to join into a single view (for export) which has a single row per secondary ID and the table data concatenated into a single field per table.

```
tbl-1 
id | adid | ImImage1 | ImName2 
1 | 1 | Im_a |  Nm _a
2 | 1 | Im_b |  Nm _b
3 | 1 | Im_c |  Nm _c
4 | 2 | Im_x |  Nm _x
5 | 2 | Im_y |  Nm _y
6 | 2 | Im_z |  Nm _z

tbl-2 
id | adid | ImImage1 | ImName1 
1 | 1 | Im_d |  Nm _d
2 | 1 | Im_e |  Nm _e
3 | 1 | Im_f |  Nm _f
4 | 2 | Im_u |  Nm _u
5 | 2 | Im_v |  Nm _v
6 | 2 | Im_w |  Nm_w

Result

adid | ImImage1-tbl1 | ImName2-tbl1 | ImImage1-tbl2 | ImName1-tbl2 
1   Im_a, Im_b, Im_c  |  Nm _a, Nm _b, Nm _c, |  Im_d, Im_e, Im_f, | Nm _d, Nm _e, Nm _f 
2   Im_x, Im_y, Im_z  |  Nm _x, Nm _y, Nm _x  |  Im_u, Im_v, Im_w  | Nm _u, Nm _v, Nm _w
```

At the moment, all I seem to be able to produce is a very long list which looks like table 1 has appended to table 2 (a row for each individual `adid` entry)

Would it be better to create a view first that concatenates each table into just 1 row per `adid`, then create a new view to join them and add the other two fields? or is there a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: Do you have a separate `ads` table, with one row per `adid`?

Comment: Yes - the adid comes from a 3rd table (with just one row per adid so could be used to join tbl-1 and tbl-2 ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most efficient way to do this is using SQL Server's XML Extensions to concatenate the rows into a single row:

```
SELECT  ads.ADID,
        [ImImage1-tbl1] = STUFF(i1.val.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        [ImName2-tbl1] = STUFF(n1.val.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        [ImImage1-tbl2] = STUFF(i2.val.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        [ImName1-tbl2] = STUFF(n2.val.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    AdTable AS Ads
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ', ' + ImImage1
            FROM    tbl1 AS t
            WHERE   t.AdID = ads.ADID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS i1 (val)
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ', ' + ImName2
            FROM    tbl1 AS t
            WHERE   t.AdID = ads.ADID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS n1 (val)
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ', ' + ImImage1
            FROM    tbl2 AS t
            WHERE   t.AdID = ads.ADID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS i2 (val)
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ', ' + ImName1
            FROM    tbl2 AS t
            WHERE   t.AdID = ads.ADID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS n2 (val);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d37e/1)**